# How to redirect ip to address iptables

Tags: iptables

I would like to know if is there a way to redirect the internal ip to another ip, but the second ip is Dynamically so i need to put an address, is there a way?

Example:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --dest 192.168.1.26 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-dest dynamicip.noip.org
```

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid that that is not possible.